# \\p{Punct} behavior in my android app

Tags: java, android, regex

This is my regex – `“[\\w\\d\\p{Punct}]+”`

It is very strange behavior of `\\p{Punct}` in my app.
According to the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> \p{Punct} - Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

But in my app this tag always omits this characters: “$”, “+”, “<”, “>”, “=”,  “^”, “`”, ”|”, ”~”

```
abc!d => true
abc#d => true
abd$d => false
abc<>d = > false
```

etc.

I tried to use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\w\d\p{Punct}]+", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

There was no an effect.

Anny suggestions what I am doing wrong?

P.S.:
I use TextWatcher for it. I do it like this:

```
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // I am checking it here
            // if if(!s.toString().matches("[\\w\\d\\p{Punct}]+")) => do something
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

          };
```

When I added this `TextWatcher` to `MyEditText`:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: @anubhava I tried it, but without any effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `\p{Punct}` matches the POSIX `[:punct:]` character class symbols that *also include symbols, `\p{S}`*.

**To avoid matching the strings without symbols you need**:

```
"^[\\w\\p{P}]+$"
```

Also, note that on Android, `\w`, `\p{P}` and `\p{S}` are Unicode-aware by default.

Besdides, `\w` already matches digits, there is no point adding both `\w` and `\d` into the same character class `[...]`.

Comment: Thank you, yes, It works! But the question is how not to match the string only  with English characters? Something like this "[a-zA-Z\\p{P}\\p{S}]+" ?